# What if I don't join someone for postdoc to whom I previously applied

Tags: funding, postdocs

I am a PhD student in applied mathematics. I have submitted my PhD thesis and started applying for postdoc positions. Now suppose I informally email somebody and suppose he says that he has no funding currently and once he has funding he will inform me. Now, suppose at the time he has funding, I have some better option, so I don't join him. Can that create a bad impression of me to him ?

Comment: Yes of course. But it depends on the supervisor's personality. From experience, when it happened, I would think twice if I were to be approached by that same person, if our paths crossed again.

Comment: Define "better option". However, I do not think that this would create a bad impression. You have not committed to anything. For starters, you would need to apply for the job with them - its not like they are going to email you saying "I've got funding and want you on board! When can you start?". [Maybe only send these tentative emails to people you know already, and in particular only to people who would understand you having a better offer.]

Comment: (Also, you have not "applied". You have "informally emailed". These are completely different things! So your title is misleading.)

Comment: I think the time frame is important too. If the funding comes in 1-2 weeks later, then that may not leave the best impression. Otherwise, it is normal and expected that PhD students as well as temporary postdocs will look for many different positions. So it is not unusual to find yourself offered a position in one place while having already secured another. - The one case where it WILL leave a very negative impression is if you have actively committed to a position and then not decide to take it up.

Comment: No, you're a free agent and presumably need a job to survive. You'll want to lock that in with a commitment from somewhere ASAP, not the day before you become unemployed/evicted/etc, much less well after when he finally comes around if ever. If he was expecting funding (or even a decision about it) any time soon and wanted to hire you with it if successful, he could've told you and then there would be a decision to angst about. But this situation is worth nothing.

Comment: Reformulation of your question: “I acted in a way that any sane person would behave when placed in the same situation. Can this create a bad impression of me in the eyes of the professor?” Not _reasonably_, no. Unreasonably? Of course it can - many people can and do hold unreasonable opinions of others.

Answer (score 4):

If your situation has genuinely changed—six months or a year go by and you’re working as a postdoctoral or researcher somewhere else, why would you be expected to give up your position? This seems like a very one-sided transaction and unfair to you. Might the professor hold a grudge? It’s possible, but anybody who does hold a grudge in such a scenario is thinking primarily about their own needs rather than your mutual benefit.

Answer (score 1):

My idea of it would be that the first time you made him an offer but he rejected, while the next time he is making you an offer and you are rejecting. Lack of funding is just as good reason as having a better option. No grudge is due or rightful on either side. He may be a bit upset, of course (like you might have been upset when *he* said "no"), but if he goes mad at you, it merely means that you've made the right choice going elsewhere.